# A bit confused whether this code is coping data while passing as argument

Tags: c++, winapi

This is regarding passing value to function by pointer. If someone can suggest me how to overcome this by passing reference would be very beneficial.

```
char *cBuff = m_RegistryCrypting.GetDecryptedValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\zztest", "MachineID");

char *CRegistryCrypting::GetDecryptedValue(HKEY hHeadKey, char *pSubKey, char *pValueName)
{
  DWORD dwDataSiz = 0;
  char *cBuff = GetRegValue(hHeadKey, pSubKey, pValueName, &dwDataSiz);
  if(cBuff != NULL)
  {
...
...
....
  }
}

char *CRegistryCrypting::GetRegValue(HKEY hHeadKey, char *pSubKey, char *pValueName, DWORD *pActualSize)
{
  DWORD dwType = REG_BINARY;
  char *pReceivedVal = NULL;
  DWORD dwDataSize = 0;
  HKEY hKey = NULL;

  if(RegCreateKeyEx(hHeadKey, pSubKey, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return NULL;

  if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey, pValueName, 0, &dwType,(PBYTE)NULL, &dwDataSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
  }
....
....
.....
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. What do you want to pass by reference and why?

Comment: How to overcome *what*? That you forgot to make your parameters `const`?

Answer (score 2):

Taking this line:

```
char *CRegistryCrypting::GetRegValue(HKEY hHeadKey, char *pSubKey, 
                                     char *pValueName, DWORD *pActualSize)
```

The *pointers* are all passed by value, so those pointer values are copied - but the data those pointers point to is *not* copied.  Passing a pointer (or any basic type) by reference will not be any more efficient than passing it by value.

That's not to say there isn't a nicer way to define this function signature, and passing by reference comes into it:

```
using namespace std;
string CRegistryCrypting::GetRegValue(HKEY hHeadKey, const string& subKey, 
                                      const string& valueName, DWORD &actualSize)
```

Now when writing the internals of the function:

- We don't have to worry about string lengths or null termination.
- The string objects are passed by reference so are passed efficiently
- The fact that the arguments are *const* references means the caller can pass anything that a std::string can be constructed from.
- I'm assuming that `actualSize` is an out parameter, as a non const reference the value can be changed within the function.
- The return is passed by value, so there is a copy taking place (which might be optimised out) but we do want to give the function caller a new object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion is quite correct, but in my scenario using string will cause lot of rework.

Comment: @hypheni Then rework it.